# Azure - Reverse Hub/Spoke Design ; Policy VPN Workaround

Tags: azure, vnet

Due to a VNet only allowing for a single static gateway, and my onprem location gateways not supporting route based VPNs, I want to see if this is poss.

- Having a resources in a single vnet.
- Create a new VNet for each
  policy based VPN, containing a static gateway.
- Then VNet peer these Vnets into the one containing all the resources.
- Use routing to direct traffic into each of the "spokes". As the "Use Remote Gateway" option is only allowed to be configured on a one of the VNet
  peerings.

Comment: Why is this being marked down?

Answer (score -1):

Oh my, even if that thing works it will be horrific to maintain.

Just spin up a Linux VM with [StrongSwan](https://www.strongswan.org/) on-prem and IKEv2 to Azure:

```
conn azure
    authby=secret
    type=tunnel
    leftsendcert=never
    left=40.127.xxx.xxx
    leftsubnet=10.4.0.0/19,10.0.0.0/24 #Azure side
    right=172.31.22.44
    rightsubnet=10.1.0.0/16,192.168.3.0/24,192.168.4.0/24 #on-prem
    keyexchange=ikev2
    auto=start
```

Comment: Problem is multiple sites have gateways so ideally need to make the change within Azure.

Comment: Time to replace those devices. Else you introduce unnecessary complexity and risk which is a much worse business proposal than investing in a bunch of branch routers. I guess it's a business case rather than a technical one.

Comment: This would all depend on the solution. Seems strange there is no better options